# Gradle, Apache TomEE - TomEEWebappClassLoader loader constraint violation

Tags: java, gradle, apache-tomee

The gradle project runtime at Apache TomEE plus has the error

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance
> of org/apache/tomee/catalina/TomEEWebappClassLoader) previously
> initiated loading for a different type with name
> "javax/faces/context/ExternalContext"     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2489)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
> at
> org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:184)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
> at
> org.apache.tomee.myfaces.TomEEWebConfigProvider.getFacesServletMappings(TomEEWebConfigProvider.java:36)
> at
> org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:163)
> at
> org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:103)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

The gradle.properties

```
dependencies {
    compile files('lib/javaee-api-7.0.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'WebContent/WEB-INF/lib', include: '**/*.jar')
    
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.jglue.cdi-unit', name: 'cdi-unit', version: '3.1.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito' ,name: 'mockito-all', version:'1.10.19'
    compile group: 'org.apache.shiro', name: 'shiro-all', version: '1.3.2'
    compile group: 'jaxen', name: 'jaxen', version: '1.1.6'
    compile 'org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7'
}
```

The jar files in WEB-INF/lib
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKzSi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error might happen when your module provide classes that are already provided by javax.faces.context.ExternalContext.  A simple way to fix this error is declaring the related library as a dependency in your custom module and setting a provided scope in gradle by the runtimeOnly configuration.

Comment: used compileOnly for javaee-api not a library jar, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while using while using faces api with tomee plus version 10.0.27 and maven as build tool.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The library faces-api is provided by default in tomee, adding it to the pom.xml file with the default `compile` scope would result in a similar error `java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation...`.

The solution is to either remove the dependency (Intellij was not happy, and i had no auto-complete in my xhtml files, but the app runs with no error on the server). and the better solution is to make the dependency as `provided` like so:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```